# date based nth record in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, range

I'm creating a jquery based web graph that displays weather data. The data is loaded via Ajax -> PHP -> MySQL. The MySQL database contains a record of various parameters for each minute for the last 10 years... (So a HUGE amount of records). I want users to be able to generate a graph for a custom date range, but limit the number of data I pull for date ranges longer than a few days. Ie, if they query for a weeks worth of data, my php code should return only 1 data value per hour. 
I don't want to do any averaging, or server side processing of that sort - I want to retrieve only every nth record from mysql - so that I get a manageable amount of data.

My problem is, my database doesn't have a record number field, and I CANNOT MODIFY the format of the database. Is there a way that I could do this based on the actual date values? Like say cast to unix timestamp, then only select the record if the date is divisible by some number? (I would calculate the number based off of the length of the time range, to pull a fixed number of points)

Any thoughts on good ways to do this? If there was a solution that would allow me to directly select even time intervals, that would be ideal. (ie. every 5 minutes, 10 minutes, 1 hr, 5 hrs, etc.)

EDIT: the field is MySQL dateTime format!! Thanks for asking for the clarification!

Comment: In what format is the time stored in the database (is the column a mysql datetime or unix timestamp column)? And is that column indexed?

Comment: Can you add your table details?

Comment: Sorry! Thanks for the comments. It's a MySQL datetime column!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [MOD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod) and [UNIX_TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) functions in your SQL WHERE clause

`SELECT * FROM WEATHER WHERE MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Time), Divisor) = 0`

Will get you only records with Times that are divisible by Divisor. The Divisor would be whatever time increment you'd like to grab data for (300 for every 5 minutes, 5400 for every 1.5 hours, etc.).

Since UNIX Time uses a 32 bit int, your standard INT data type in MySQL will do just fine.

Comment: If the query is used for large intervals (ex.: 5 years) then this query will not be fast enough. In any case I think it is difficult to find a good solution without database modification. The problem is that any calculation on datetime field means that index of this field will not be used in the query.

Comment: Looks good. That's pretty much what I was looking for. I'll try it tomorrow and report back. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Dirk, I just made an assumption that it's datetime field, I didn't know too :) But it was not about datetime field, the same problem is for any field type.

Comment: @Karolis - I'm fine with limiting the date range to something reasonable... any recommendations? 6 mos?

Comment: @Amy, I my opinion this solution is good enough, but the speed depends on many factors, so you should test it for objective results. It was just my own considerations :)

Comment: In order to be able to use an index lookup with this you'd need to add a column holding the reverse of the string representation of the unix timestamp in an appropriate base conversion and do a LIKE comparison on this

Comment: This works great for me, as far as fixing my render time issues. Rendering the points in my chart was the issue, not the query time. (Changed it "=" instead of "=="). However, I'm not getting back evenly spaced points, and it's fairly apparent.  So I guess I'll declare a counter variable in the query, and then mod on that?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a DATETIME to a UNIX timestamp, divide by the number of seconds in the interval you want (10 minutes in the following example), and then use GROUP BY to reduce to one row per distinct value.

```
SELECT FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime_col)/600) AS ts, * FROM WEATHER 
WHERE datetime_col BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY ts
```

This isn't going to be very quick, because it has to calculate `ts` for every row, and then group by that as an unindexed column.

Also this depends on nonstandard behavior of MySQL, which permits ambiguous GROUP BY queries.  That is, it returns some arbitrary row from the group, determined by the storage engine.  In practice, it's the first row as stored physically, but this can get confusing depending on storage engine, covering indexes, etc.

Alternative:  You can use a user variable to count rows, and return only the first row when the interval changes.

```
SET @interval := 0;
SET @row := 0;
SELECT t.* FROM (
SELECT (@i:=FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime_col)/600)),
  IF(@interval<>@i),@row:=0,@row:=@row+1) AS row, @interval:=@i, *
FROM WEATHER
WHERE datetime_col BETWEEN ? AND ?
) AS t
WHERE t.row = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Like say cast to unix timestamp, then only select the record if the date is divisible by some number?

The problem with this, and most approaches is that you still have to read all the consecutive points (unless you've got indexed columns containing various representations of the timestamp) so you might be reducing the size of the resultset but not the amount of work required to extract it.

Can you create a new table (doesn't have to be in the same database / server - you can still connect to the raw data using the federated engine)? That way you could set up a table of timestamps with different degrees of granularity, in a towers of hanoi sequence e.g.

```
date time       level
-------------   -----
201101010000    0
201101010010    6
201101010020    6
201101010030    5
201101010040    6
201101010050    6
201101010100    4
201101010110    6
201101010120    6
201101010130    5
...
201101020000    3
...
```

That way you could SELECT from this tale at an appropriate level of granularity and join to the underlying rawdata.

The above coul be imlemented as a functio to aggregate data - but without atable to lookup **from** you still need to read all the intervening rows in the src data.

> If there was a solution that would allow me to directly select even time intervals

Something like....

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(yourdate, SUBSTR('%Y%m%d%H%i%s',0,2*@level)) as t,
 AVG(value)
 FROM yourtable
 WHERE yourdate BETWEEN @datestart AND @dateend
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(yourdate, SUBSTR('%Y%m%d%H%i%s',0,2*@level))
 ORDER BY 1;
```

(as above - without a second table to join to or another way of selecting only the reuired sampl of data using an index, there's no performance penalty in using the aggregate fn).